# How do I remove square brackets and comma's from a text file?

Tags: bash

I have a text file that gets written from a Spark SQL query. It's written as a text file with square brackets separated by commas like below. I need to remove the brackets and the commas. So far I have `sed -e 's/]//g' -e 's/,//g'` $filename but this is only removing the end bracket and all the commas.

```
[371590146, ,2019-04-28, ,123.2]
[371712941, ,2019-04-29, ,128.72]
[371828179, ,2019-04-30, ,148.35]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' -e 's/,//g' file
371590146 2019-04-28 123.2
371712941 2019-04-29 128.72
371828179 2019-04-30 148.35
```

or:

```
$ sed -e 's/[][,]//g' file
371590146 2019-04-28 123.2
371712941 2019-04-29 128.72
371828179 2019-04-30 148.35
```

or:

```
$ sed -Ee 's/\[|\]|,//g' file
371590146 2019-04-28 123.2
371712941 2019-04-29 128.72
371828179 2019-04-30 148.35
```

Note that `[` and `]` are regex-active characters.  If you want them to be treated literally as square brackets, they should be escaped with `\`.  (Sometimes a program is smart enough to know that you meant it literally, as in the code in the question, but it is best practice not to count on that.)

`[][,]` means any of `]`, `[`, or `,`. `[...]` is called a *bracket expression*.  It matches any character contained within the brackets.

`\[|\]|,` also means any of `]`, `[`, or `,`.  In extended regular expressions (`-E` option), the character `|` separates *branches*.  This matches if the regex on either side of the `|` matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -d '[],' <file
```

Output:

```
371590146 2019-04-28 123.2
371712941 2019-04-29 128.72
371828179 2019-04-30 148.35
```

---

See: `man tr`

Answer (score 0):

Just because I like to add alternatives (Cyrus' answer is much better, as are all of John1024's), here's an all-bash solution that would be a lot slower but also works.

```
while IFS=",][ " read -a f
do echo ${f[@]} # proper quotes add an extra space before each field
done < file
```